# How can I handle "Too many mail in folder" error when selecting an inbox with imaplib?

Tags: email, imaplib

I'm reading recent 100~200 emails periodically.

As the number of mails in the inbox increases, I'm getting an error.

```
res = self.mail.select()
print(res)
```

> NO
> [b'[UNAVAILABLE] Too many mail in folder.']

It seems that this occurs when there are more than 500,000 mails.

How can I handle this?

If moving old emails to another folder is the only way, I cannot find `move` command in the [document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html#).

Should I do multiple actions, such as copy and delete?

Comment: It looks like you can’t handle it from IMAP once it has happened.  You will probably need to use the native client of your server.  To prevent it from happening, use .uid to generate a MOVE command if your server supports it (check the `CAPABILITIES`, or use COPY/STORE \Deleted/EXPUNGE cycle to move them.)  You are using UIDs right?

Comment: @Max Yes, I'm using UID. So, you mean there's no other way than moving read mails to another folder. I cannot find other similar issues. Is this a server-specific setting? I mean, can this be resolved by the server manager?

Comment: There’s no protocol limit to the number of messages in a server (maybe 2^31-1...), but obviously this server has some sort of internal limit.  Since you can’t `select` the folder, you can’t do anything with it via IMAP, which is always the first step in working with a folder.